# PHP count number of entries in a SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I have a launch page that accepts emails. I am trying to count the total number of emails in the table. However, I am struggling to get it to work. The sql seems to be accurate, because I ran the sql script in phpmyadmin and it returned the correct value. However, when I do a var_dump of the variable that I assigned the sql script it does not return the correct value. Any suggestions?

PHP

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $query = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES ('$email')");
    $query->execute();
    $editEmail = $db->exec("SELECT COUNT(email) FROM launch_email");
    var_dump($editEmail);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
exit;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: You have a missing closing brace `}` after `exit;` --- Try and show the error message itself using `exit( $e->getMessage() );`

Comment: You will need to fetch it after execute.

Comment: You can use `AS value_name` to assign a name and access, otherwise it will be returned as key-pair `COUNT(email)`. So: `SELECT COUNT(email) AS ttl_emails FROM launch_email`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry I didn't highlight and select all of the code from my text editor. It has a closing bracket.

Comment: No problemo, just checking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::exec()` does not return results from a select statement - you should use `PDO::query` instead:

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $query = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES ('$email')");
    $query->execute();

    // dummy traversable - it'll only loop once
    for ($db->query("SELECT COUNT(email) AS cnt FROM launch_email") as $row) {
        print $row['cnt'];
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
}
exit;
```

Comment: I got this error on the print $row['cnt'] line; PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array...

Comment: @RyanSalmons arg, yeah, forgot `query` doesn't return an array but a traversable `PDOStatement`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$editEmail = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(email) as email_count FROM launch_email");    
$fet = $db->fetch();

if($fet['email_count'] > 0)
{
   // Email exists
}
else
{
    // Email does not exist
}
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `$db` is an instance of `PDO`.

The problem is that you are using the `exec` method of the `PDO` class, which simply returns the number of rows affected by the specified SQL query.

You will need to use the `query` method instead. That will return an instance of `PDOStatement`. If you call the `fetchColumn` method on this instance, you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to figure it out...This is what I needed:

PHP

```
function get_count($count_id, $count) {

    $output = "";

    $output = $output . $count["email_count"];

    return $output;
}


try {
    $totalEmail = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(email) as email_count FROM launch_email");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Date could not be retrieved from database.";
    exit;
}
$countTotal = $totalEmail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($countTotal as $count_id => $count) { 
    echo get_count($count_id,$count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have to return count then you can use "print_r($editEmail)" also please check it.

Or try this one

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(email) FROM launch_email"; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); 
echo $number_of_rows;
```